# How to make user submit information in a particular order?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a user input form in Android by displaying the following input views on an activity screen:

1. Spinner (Get a location from pre-filled options)
2. EditText (Get exact address)
3. Spinner (Get 2nd location from pre-filled options)
4. EditText (Get exact address)
5. Date
6. Time

Now, I want to allow the user to fill the above fields only in the particular order mentioned above, eg. user should not be able to see options in 2nd spinner unless she selects one from the 1st spinner, or user should not be able to fill EditText fields before selecting option from spinners...

How can we ensure this?

Comment: make all fields disabled, except 1st one, and for each View based on it's type implement the proper event handler, ex for spinner: `onItemSelected()` to enabled next field (view) and so on.